# Linear Transformations with the Standard Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems, change-of-basis

Let $A'$ denote the standard (coordinate) basis in $\mathbb R^n$ and suppose that $T\colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is a linear transformation with matrix $A$ so that $T(x) = Ax$. Further, suppose that $A$ is invertible. Let $B$ be another (non-standard) basis for $\mathbb R^n$, and denote by $A_{(B)}$ the matrix for $T$ with respect to $B$.

a) Prove that $A_{(B)}$ is also an invertible matrix.

b) If $\{x_1,\dots,x_k\}$ is a linearly independent set in $\mathbb R^n$, prove that 
$$\left\{A_{(B)}[x_1]_{(B)}\dots A_{(B)}[x_k]_{(B)}\right\}$$ is also linearly independent, where $[x]_{(B)}$ denotes the $B$-coordinate vector of $x.$

Ok I think I understand now that A_B = P(A_E)P^-1, where P is the change of coordinates matrix. And since A_E is invertible (it says so in the problem) and obviously P is invertible, then the product PAP^-1 gives an invertible matrix. Is P from standard to B coordinates, and P^-1 is from B back to E? And for part (b), I am lost.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) you will find some basics on latex formatting. This should help you making your posts more readable ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear Transformation and Change of Basis](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2223009/linear-transformation-and-change-of-basis)

Answer (score 0):

Some hints: Let $E$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$. Then $A_{(E)} = A$ (Why?)

a) Do you know how you can transform matrix $A_{(E)}$ to matrix $A_{(B)}$? Do you know how to characterize invertibility via determinants?

b) How does the linear mapping $f \colon x_i \mapsto [x_i]_{(B)}$ look like (sometimes it's called coordinate transformation)? Is it invertible? What do you know about images of linearly independent vectors under invertible linear mappings? (indeed, injectivity will suffice for this last question)

Comment: @John: As I understood you post, $A_{(E)}$ is the matrix corresponding to the linear mapping with respect to basis $E$. Unless $T$ is the identity mapping, $A_{(E)}$ won't be the identity matrix.

Comment: @John: Why would $A$ be a basis? Your original post says it's a matrix.

Comment: I apologize, the question uses two different A's. A' is the standard basis and A is the matrix. So A_(B) would be the matrix [ (A(x1))_E....(A(xn)_E ]?

Comment: @John: No. $A_{(B)}$ would be the matrix $[ T(b_1)_{(B)} \dots T(b_n)_{(B)} ]$ if $B$ is the basis consisting of the vectors $b_1,\dots,b_n$.

Comment: I'm shaky on coordinates, I apologize. How do I transform A_(E) to A_(B)?

Comment: @John: I'm sorry, but time does not allow for me to lecture you on basics of linear algebra. You should study a book on this subject and if questions remain e.g. ask them on math.stackexchange. As a general advice: Always, before trying to "solve" a problem in mathematics, make sure you "understand" the problem in terms of the definitions used to formulate the problem.

Comment: Ok I think I understand now that A_B = P(A_E)P^-1, where P is the change of coordinates matrix. And since A_E is invertible (it says so in the problem) and obviously P is invertible, then the product PAP^-1 gives an invertible matrix? Am I close here?

Comment: @John Sounds good!

Comment: for part (b), if I have {x1...xk} as linearly independent then c1...ck are all = 0 such that c1x1+...+ckxk=0. Then applying A and using T as a linear transformation I have c1A(x1)...ckA(xk)=0. From here can I multiply each a on the left by P and on the right by P^-1 to get A_B for all A's? but how do I transform each x and maintain linear independence?