# Linear Transformation and Change of Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A'$ denote the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and suppose that $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear transformation with matrix $A$, so that $T(x)=Ax$. Further suppose that $A$ is invertible.  Let $B$ be another (non-standard) basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, and denote by $A_B$ the matrix for $T$ with respect to $B$.

a) Prove that $A_B$ is also an invertible matrix.

b) If $\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$ is a linearly independent set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, prove that $\{A_B[x_1]_B,\ldots,A_B[x_k]_B\}$ is also linearly independent, where $[x]_B$ denotes that $B$-coordinate vector of $x$.

So for part (b), how would I construct this proof? I have that c1A(x1)...ckA(xk)=0 where c1...ck all = 0, but how to I change this to A_B[xk]_B? I know I can multiply all the As on the left by P and on the right by P^-1 to make all the A's into A_B, but what about the x's?

Comment: Are you possibly the same user who asked [this version](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2222675/11619) also? Then you may want to read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), and also follow the instructions there.

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ is the change of basis matrix, then $A_B = PAP^{-1}.$ By definition, $A_B[x]_B = [Ax]_B$ and since $[]_B$ is an isomorphism, it preserves basis.

Comment: I thought that PAP^-1 only works if there is a basis of eigenvectors? How do we know that there exists a basis for R^n of eigenvectors?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant to say "P is the change of basis matrix." My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: So Since A_B = PAP^-1, then PAP^-1 = D (the diagonal matrix with eigenvalues) and D is invertible so that is how we know A_B is invertible?

Comment: I am not considering  eigenvalues but the matrix of change of basis.

Comment: Ok I am just confused as to how this shows that A_B is invertible?

Comment: A change of basis matrix is always invertible because the matrix of reversing the change is the inverse matrix

Comment: You called P the change of basis matrix so that means that P is invertible, but how is A_B?

Comment: A_B is the product of invertible matrices

Comment: So for part (b), how would I construct this proof? I have that c1A(x1)...ckA(xk)=0 where c1...ck all = 0, but how to I change this to A_B[xk]_B? I know I can multiply all the As on the left by P and on the right by P^-1 to make all the A's into A_B, but what about the x's?

Comment: @John: Why are you asking this question twice? Consider merging your accounts and refrain from reposting questions.